# Change any button on android when user long press

Tags: java, android, button

I have some button, say btnA1, btnA2, btnA3 and i want user can change button text on long press. When user long press on any button, it give dialog for user to fill button text and some textView. Here is my code :

```
btnA1.setOnLongClickListener(new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    dialogForm();
    return true;
  }
});
```

Here is the dialogForm function :

```
private void dialogForm(){
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
inflater = getLayoutInflater();
dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.macro_form, null);
dialog.setView(dialogView);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
dialog.setTitle("Macro Form");

txtMacroName    = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtMacroName);
txtMacroStatus    = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtMacroValue);

dialog.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    macroName    = txtMacroName.getText().toString();
    macroStatus    = txtMacroStatus.getText().toString();

    dialog.dismiss();
  }
});

dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
});
dialog.show();
}
```

How i can detect which button pressed so before dialog,dismiss(), only that button will change;

Comment: You should add tags (like [android] or [java]) to make your question visible for expert in given technology.

Comment: You can pass button instance to 'dialogForm()'. Like 'dialogForm(btnA1);' and 'private void dialogForm(Button b1){. . b1.setText(macroName    );}'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to Mr. Sibin Davis combined with Mr. Karan Sandhu, here is final code

```
btnA1.setOnLongClickListener(new Button.OnLongClickListener() {
  @Override
  public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),ttlA1,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    dialogForm(btnA1); // <---- add this
    return true;
  }
});
```

and function dialogForm() :

```
private void dialogForm(final Button b1){ //<-- add this
dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
inflater = getLayoutInflater();
dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.macro_form, null);
dialog.setView(dialogView);
dialog.setCancelable(true);
dialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
dialog.setTitle("Macro Form");

txtMacroName    = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtMacroName);
txtMacroStatus    = (EditText) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.txtMacroValue);

dialog.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    macroName    = txtMacroName.getText().toString();
    macroStatus    = txtMacroStatus.getText().toString();
    b1.setText(macroName); // <---- add this
    dialog.dismiss();
  }

});

dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
    dialog.dismiss();
  }
});
dialog.show();
}
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Try giving id's to your buttons, So that when user selects a button and types the text then in dialog you can set that text to that particular button and the dismiss it. Then in set button text

```
dialog.setPositiveButton("Submit", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    macroName    = txtMacroName.getText().toString();
    macroStatus    = txtMacroStatus.getText().toString();

    dialog.dismiss();
  }
});
```

In setPositivebutton method just get the edittext's value(i.e getText().toString) and then set it to button like btn.setText(edittext's value).